# keep focus of css style even if other button clicked

Tags: html, css, button

I found similar questions like:

- [How to keep focuse css style after clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772566/how-to-keep-focuse-css-style-after-clicking-a-button-the-style-disappears-after)
- [Keep style of button after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298945/keep-style-of-button-after-click)

But the style will still change with this solutions, if a other button is clicked. The button should change to the focus style after click and to the normal one after clicked again. I made 3 different buttons with the Bootstrap css.

```css
#btn-none, .btn-warning {
  color: #797979;
  background: rgba(247,247,247, 0.710);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 350px;
  left:100.5%;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
}
.btn-warning:hover {
  color: #414141;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.btn-warning:focus, .btn-warning.focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: #414141;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.btn-warning.disabled, .btn-warning:disabled {
  color: #414141;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.show > .btn-warning.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #414141;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,
.show > .btn-warning.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button ONCLICK=" document.getElementById('Show'); document.getElementById('Hide'); document.getElementById('SectionName').style.display='none'" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse3">
  <img class="buttonimage" src="data/img/icon_h2.png" />
  <a id="content-mobile">lorem1</a>
</button><br><br>

<button ONCLICK=" document.getElementById('Show'); document.getElementById('Hide'); document.getElementById('SectionName').style.display='none'" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse2">
  <img class="buttonimage" src="data/img/icon_efuel.png" />
    <a id="content-mobile">lorem2</a>
</button><br><br>

<button ONCLICK=" document.getElementById('Show'); document.getElementById('Hide'); document.getElementById('SectionName').style.display='none'" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse">
  <img class="buttonimage" src="data/img/icon_electric.png" />
    <a id="content-mobile">lorem3</a>
</button>
```

Comment: You will have to use Javascript for advanced logics like this.
For some cases you may be able to use `:visited`, but this will permanently give them a style.