# Keep style of current tab navbar item

Tags: javascript, python, css, plotly-dash

I am building a Dash web app with two tabs, a map and a FAQ tab. It looks like this:
[dash app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQGLe.jpg)

As you see I have defined a navbar to navigate through the tabs, it works as expected. It is defined as follows:

```
dbc.Navbar(
    dbc.Container(
        children=[
            dbc.NavbarToggler(id='navbar-toggler', n_clicks=0),
            dbc.Collapse(
                dbc.Nav(
                    [
                        dbc.NavItem(
                            dbc.NavLink(
                                'Map',
                                href='/',
                                class_name='map-navlink',
                                id='map-navlink'
                            )
                        ),
                        dbc.NavItem(
                            dbc.NavLink(
                                'FAQ',
                                href='/faq',
                                class_name='faq-navlink',
                                id='faq-navlink'
                            )
                        )
                    ]
                ),
                id='navbar-collapse',
                navbar=True
            ),
        ],
        fluid=True,
        class_name='navbar'
    ),
    color='dark',
    dark=True
)
```

What I want to achieve now is to change the style of the tab the user is looking. I have already achieved through CSS that the styles are changed when the user clicks the navbar item. The CSS I used is as follows.

```
.map-navlink {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 0.5vw;
}
.map-navlink:focus {
    color: #26BF64;
    background-color: grey;
}
.map-navlink:hover {
    color: #26BF64;
}


.faq-navlink {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 0.5vw;
}
.faq-navlink:focus {
    color: #26BF64;
    background-color: grey;
}
.faq-navlink:hover {
    color: #26BF64;
}
```

With this CSS, when a user clicks the Map navlink or the FAQ navlink the styles are correctly changed. However, when they click anywhere else the styles are reverted to their original state. Apart from that, I would also like that when the dash app is first loaded the style of the Map navlink is also changed.

I have already found this 3 SO questions:

[Keep style of button after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298945/keep-style-of-button-after-click)

[How to keep focuse css style after clicking a button (the style disappears after clicking anywhere)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772566/how-to-keep-focuse-css-style-after-clicking-a-button-the-style-disappears-after)

[keep focus of css style even if other button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70693714/keep-focus-of-css-style-even-if-other-button-clicked)

But I can't seem to make it work.

Can anyone help me?

This is my first posted question here so I apologize in advance if I have made any mistakes. If more information is needed please ask for it and I will happily provide it.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally achieved what I wanted and it was much simpler than what I thought. I have just added the parameter `active='exact'` in both Navlinks as follows:

```
dbc.NavItem(
    dbc.NavLink(
        'Mapa',
        href='/',
        class_name='map-navlink',
        id='map-navlink',
        active='exact' # This is new
    )
),
dbc.NavItem(
    dbc.NavLink(
        'FAQ',
        href='/faq',
        class_name='faq-navlink',
        id='faq-navlink',
        active='exact' # This is new
    )
)
```

And once that is done I changed my CSS styles as follows:

```
.map-navlink.active {
    color: #26BF64 !important;
    background-color: grey;
}

.faq-navlink.active {
    color: #26BF64 !important;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

I needed to add the `!important` because Dash adds some parent classes to the Navlink and it inherits attributes from them (color being one of them), thus my styles were not being correctly applied.

With that changes my dash web-app works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to toggle a css class

Example:

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav > a[data-class]");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("main > section[class]");

navLinks.forEach(navLink =>
  navLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sections.forEach(sec => sec.classList.toggle("active", sec.classList.contains(navLink.dataset.class)));
    navLinks.forEach(link => link.classList.toggle("active", navLink == link));
  })
);
```

```css
main > section{
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
}
main > section:not(.active){
  display: none;
}
nav > a{
  padding: .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav > a.active{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a data-class="home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a data-class="about">About</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <section class="home active">
    Home content
  </section>
  <section class="about">
    About content
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Do you know a way of translating this into dash? I have tried to implement it but to no success.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know dash. Have you tried inspecting the html output of "dash" in you're browsers dev-tools? Maybe you can spot the error there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have already achieved to set the same structure as you, however I have a problem. My nav item equivalent to your "home" one has the class "map-navlink", and the section that actually holds the map has the class "map-div". I see that in your answer both the navlink and the section have the same class, is this mandatory? If it is not, how should I adjust your code to work?

Comment: I've editted my code example. Let me know if thats what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: I think I have spotted a problem. The div that shows when the "map-navlink" is clicked has class "map-div". Because of that the `sec.classList.contains(navLink.dataset.class)` fails and nothing is displayed (I suppose this happens because of the `display: none` of the CSS). If I change the class of the div to "map-div map-navlink" the styles are not applied correctly because in my CSS file I have `.map-div {/*CSS code here*/}`. How can I correct that?

Comment: I think you just have to add the data attribute `data-class="map-div"` to the nav link. So it is connected to the right element